# Getting a raw SQL query with variables in Yii1

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii1.x

Is Yii1 has any native methods to get the raw SQL with variables built?

I try to get a complex query built on a few subqueries using `CDbExpression` and `CommandBuilder`. I got this as a result:

```
SELECT * FROM `news` `t` WHERE id IN (:ycp0, :ycp1, :ycp2, :ycp3, :ycp4) LIMIT 5
```

The dump of the criteria content:

```
CDbCriteria Object (
  [select] => *
  [condition] => id IN (:ycp0, :ycp1, :ycp2, :ycp3, :ycp4)

  ...

  [params] => Array(
    [:ycp0] => CDbExpression Object(
      [expression] => SELECT id FROM `news` `t` WHERE (rubric=:rb1) AND (:im2 & `im`=:im2) LIMIT 1
      [params] => Array(
        [:rb1] => 1
        [:im2] => 2
      )
    )

    ...

  )
)
```

I expected for compiled query string like this:

```
SELECT * FROM .. WHERE id IN(
    (SELECT id FROM .. WHERE .. ORDER BY .. LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT id FROM .. WHERE .. ORDER BY .. LIMIT 1)
) ORDER BY .. LIMIT 5
```

This is what I do in my code

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria( ... );
$sql = $this->commandBuilder->createFindCommand($tableName, $criteria)->getText();
$queries[] = new CDbExpression($sql, $criteria->params);
```

Then I try to combine subqueries to one complex query

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria( ... );
$criteria->addInCondition('id', $queries);
```

And finally, I try to get the result as SQL-query

```
$sql = $this->commandBuilder->createFindCommand($tableName, $criteria)->getText();
```

Comment: try reading here http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/16154-custom-cdbconnection/page__p__81724#entry81724

Answer (score 1):

You get the SQL with params, as you have

```
$sql = $this->commandBuilder->createFindCommand($tableName, $criteria)->getText();
```

Then get the params enclosed in quotes:

```
$params = array_map(function($param) { return '"' . $param . '"'; }, $criteria->params);
```

Finally, replace the pairs:

```
echo strtr($sql, $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enableParamLogging](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#enableParamLogging-detail) in your db config (boolean). You can set it up so it's used conditionally -- make sure to not use it in production.

```
    'db' => [
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=' . $dbhost . ';port=' . $dbport . ';dbname=' . $dbname,
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => $db_user,
        'password' => $db_pass,
        'schemaCachingDuration' => 3600,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'enableProfiling' => $db_profile,
        'enableParamLogging' => $db_params,
    ],
```

Then you can add `'class'=>'CWebLogRoute'` to your `log` routes if you want to see all the output in your browser. [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebLogRoute/)

Comment: Thank you, but I need to use it in production code. Actually, I didn't know how the Yii Framework creates queries. So I needed "createInCondition" method. https://github.com/yukal/Tutvse-Yii1/blob/master/protected/models/News.php#L732
And this is what I have done: https://github.com/yukal/Tutvse-Yii1/blob/master/protected/models/News.php#L647

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

```php
$criteria = ...;
$command = $builder->createFindCommand($schema->getTable('name_of_table'), $criteria);
$results = $command->text;
```

Answer (score -2):

There are few other options to perform the same thing but i will suggest you 
should use the following

```
$results = MyModel::model()->findAllBySql("...");
```

Or you can prefer the following :
[Sub-queries ActiveRecord Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467698/sub-queries-activerecord-yii)

Comment: Well, I don't want to use this method because it needs to write much SQL text in the model, and it looks terrible. I like to use PDO.